# sqlalchemy.exc.IntegrityError: (sqlite3.IntegrityError) UNIQUE constraint failed what do i do?

Tags: python, database, sqlite, flask, flask-sqlalchemy

so ive created a user model and a form class in order to receive users data when create an account. but when i submit, an integrity error page pops up and show me the next error:

```
> sqlalchemy.exc.IntegrityError: (sqlite3.IntegrityError) UNIQUE
> constraint failed: user.email_adress [SQL: INSERT INTO user (username,
> email_adress, password_hash, budget) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)] [parameters:
> ('erickkpruneda', 'prunefeli@gmail.com', 'Guero432', 1000)]
> (Background on this error at: https://sqlalche.me/e/20/gkpj)
```

as you can see thats the data i typed on the form. whats weirder is that the data actually was saved in the database bc when i checked it, it had all the user, email and password info. so im even more confused atp
heres the code:
routes code

```
from market import app, db
from flask import render_template, redirect, url_for
from market.models import Item, User
from market.forms import RegisterForms




@app.route('/')   # decorator

def home_page():
    return render_template('home.html')

@app.route('/market')
def market():
    items = Item.query.all()
    return render_template('market.html', items = items)  



@app.route('/register', methods = ['GET', 'POST'])
def registerPage():
    form = RegisterForms()
   
    if form.validate_on_submit():
      
        user_to_create = User(username = form.username.data, email_adress = form.email.data, password_hash = form.password_1.data)
        
        db.session.add(user_to_create)
        db.session.commit()
        
      
        return redirect(url_for('market'))
    return render_template('register.html', form = form)
```

models:

```
from market import db

class User(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer(), primary_key = True)
    username = db.Column(db.String(length = 30), nullable = False, unique = True)  
    email_adress = db.Column(db.String(length = 50), nullable = False, unique = True)
    password_hash = db.Column(db.String(length = 60), nullable = False)
    budget = db.Column(db.Integer(), nullable = False, default = 1000)
    items = db.relationship('Item', backref = 'owned_user', lazy = True) 

    def __repr__(self) -> str:
        return f'User {self.username}'
```

and form:

```
from flask_wtf import FlaskForm
from wtforms import StringField, PasswordField, SubmitField

class RegisterForms(FlaskForm):
 
    username = StringField(label= 'Username: ')
    email = StringField(label= 'Email address: ')
    password_1 = PasswordField(label= 'Password:')
    password_2 = PasswordField(label= 'Confirm password: ')
    submit = SubmitField(label= 'Create account')
```

Comment: `constraint failed: user.email_adress` You tried to create a user object with the same email address as another user object.

Comment: the email already is in the database, so youz must catch the error and tell the user that it is there, maybe he only lost his password

Answer (score 0):

Try to make email validation in validate method of FlaskForm

```
class RegisterForm(FlaskForm):
   ...

   def validate(self, *args, **kwargs):
       rs = super().validate(*args, **kwargs)
       if rs:
           existing_email = User.query.filter(User.email_address == self.email).one_or_none()
           if existing_email:
               self.email.errors.append("Already exist")
               return False
       return rs
```